# Issue with corrupt querystring parameter

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

My Code is:

**index.jsp**

```
<a href="/User/music.jsp?path=/Users/Downloads/Halle & so.mp3">Hallo & so</a>
```

**music.jsp**

```
<h4><%out.print(request.getParameter("path"));%></h4>
```

but the querystring has corrupted my path variable.

**output:**

```
/User/Downloads/Halle
```

Can someone assist me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use URL encoding to fix this problem.

```
encodeURIComponent('Halle & so.mp3');
```

Problem is & is special character used to split the parameters.